# SQL - Return special rows, then generic depending on search criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table that has style codes and model codes, along with pricing information.

```
MODEL CODE - STYLE CODE - PRICE
10000      - STD        - 150.00
10500      - FEL        - 25.50
10500      - STD        - 19.90
20050      - GEK        - 130.00
20050      - FEL        - 99.99
20050      - STD        - 50.00
40330      - GEK        - 39.00
40330      - STD        - 19.00
```

You can be certain that every model code has a style code of STD available.
I want a query that can find the total price of all model codes at a certain style, but if that style doesn't exist for a specific model, it takes the standard price.

For instance, if I wanted the FEL price from this table, I'd get 293.49.
(10000-STD @ 150 + 10500-FEL @ 25.50 + 20050-FEL @ 99.99 + 40330-STD @ 19.00)

Comment: Have you had a stab at it yourself? If so, what's wrong with the query you're working on?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: We are using Microsoft SQL Server.  I'm very new ay SQL and the best I've been able to get so far is returning the summation of prices on both the target and STD rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- first select the model codes.
WITH models AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_CODE
  FROM TABLENAME
), val_list AS
(
  -- then left join back to the table and pick the style or default.
  SELECT m.MODEL_CODE, COALESCE(x.PRICE,d.PRICE) AS PRICE
  FROM models m
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME d ON d.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND d.STYLE_CODE = 'STD'
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME x ON x.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND x.STYLE_CODE = 'FEL'
),
SELECT SUM(PRICE)
FROM val_list
```

---

Note if you can't use a CTE the following will do the same thing:

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE)
FROM (
  SELECT m.MODEL_CODE, COALESCE(x.PRICE,d.PRICE) AS PRICE
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_CODE FROM TABLENAME) m
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME d ON d.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND d.STYLE_CODE = 'STD'
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME x ON x.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND x.STYLE_CODE = 'FEL'
) val_list
```

---

To see how this works, you can look at the different parts -- try

```
-- first select the model codes.
WITH models AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_CODE
  FROM TABLENAME
)
SELECT m.MODEL_CODE, x.PRICE, d.PRICE
FROM models m
LEFT JOIN TABLENAME d ON d.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND d.STYLE_CODE = 'STD'
LEFT JOIN TABLENAME x ON x.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND x.STYLE_CODE = 'FEL'
```

and

```
-- first select the model codes.
WITH models AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_CODE
  FROM TABLENAME
), val_list AS
(
  -- then left join back to the table and pick the style or default.
  SELECT m.MODEL_CODE, COALESCE(x.PRICE,d.PRICE) AS PRICE
  FROM models m
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME d ON d.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND d.STYLE_CODE = 'STD'
  LEFT JOIN TABLENAME x ON x.MODEL_CODE = m.MODEL_CODE AND x.STYLE_CODE = 'FEL'
)
SELECT *
FROM val_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it

```
  with w_styles as (
        select model_cd,
               style_cd,
               price,
               row_number() over (partition by model_cd order by case when style_cd = 'STD' then 'ZZZ' else style_cd end ) r
          from <yourtable>
         where style_cd in ( 'FEL', 'STD' )
     )
  select model_cd, style_cd, price
    from w_styles
   where r = 1
```

This just gathers up either the "FEL" or the default "STD" records, then groups them by model cd, preferring the FEL code, over STD if it's there.
Then discards what it doesn't need

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

```
declare @style as varchar(3)
set @style = 'Fel'

SELECT sum(price) as [Price]
FROM
(
SELECT 
t1.[model code], 
t1.[style code], 
t1.price
FROM myTable t1
WHERE ([style code] = @style)

UNION

SELECT 
t1.[model code], 
t1.[style code], 
t1.price
FROM myTable t1
WHERE ([style code] = 'Std')
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT null FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.[model code]= t1.[model code] and t2.[style code] =  @style)
) A
```

To step through it, this section gets each row where the style matches the style you've selected:

```
SELECT 
t1.[model code], 
t1.[style code], 
t1.price
FROM myTable t1
WHERE ([style code] = @style)
```

Then we'll stack the rest of the models into those results with a union. We only want to add rows where the model number doesn't have the queried style code. I used a self join and an exists statement to do it.

```
SELECT 
t1.[model code], 
t1.[style code], 
t1.price
FROM myTable t1
WHERE ([style code] = 'Std') -- standard codes 
AND NOT EXISTS               -- where there is not style of 'Fel'
(SELECT null FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.[model code]= t1.[model code] and t2. [style code] =  @style)
```

At this point you've got a table of all of the models, styles, and prices that you need, so you just sum the prices.